# What is the difference between LD_PRELOAD_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

What is the difference between LD_PRELOAD_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

I understand what they do, but not the particulars of how they differ.

From 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker

> The dynamic linker can be influenced into modifying its behavior
>   during either the program's execution or the program's linking.
>   Examples of this can be seen in the run-time linker manual pages for
>   various Unix-like systems. A typical modification of
>   this behavior is the use of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD
>   environment variables. These variables adjust the runtime linking
>   process by searching for shared libraries at alternate locations and
>   by forcibly loading and linking libraries that would otherwise not be,
>   respectively.

In particular, I am interested in the differences in Linux which has both LD_PRELOAD_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

https://linuxgazette.net/issue48/tag/48.html

Update:  The author of this 1999 Linux Gazette article notes in his 2013 comment below the accepted answer that LD_PRELOAD_PATH does not in fact exist.

Comment: Would you please edit this post and change LD_PRELOAD_PATH to LD_PRELOAD especially in the title? It might mislead fellows who believe that such two similar keywords exist.

Comment: Such an edit changes the point of the question which was confusion over two specific environment variables that seemed to exist because of a much earlier Linux Gazette posting.  I have however added text to the question to make sure readers understand this context.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`LD_PRELOAD` (not `LD_PRELOAD_PATH`) is a list of specific libraries (*files*) to be loaded before any other libraries, whether the program wants it or not. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a list of *directories* to search when loading libraries that would have been loaded anyway. On linux you can read `man ld.so` for more information about these and other environment variables that affect the dynamic linker.

Comment: Darn!  That was my mistake.  I put LD_PRELOAD_PATH in that old LG column when I meant to put LD_PRELOAD!  Doh!

Comment: @JimDennis ha! Didn't expect to see you here. I won't hold it against you, but on the other hand if they're taking edits... :)

Comment: I haven't done LG TAG for several years now. I have been here, and on ServerFault, Quora, FaceBook, Google+, Wikipedia and various other Wikimedia sites.  Spread too thin for "branding" but that was never my primary motivation for participating in various online fora.  (Was active on mailing lists an USENet netnews back in the days when those were a thing).  Ironically I came across this because I was wondering my my attempt to use LD_PRELOAD_PATH wasn't working --- was conflating the two earlier this afternoon, too.

Comment: That works well until you have to start something under `root` from a non-privileged account. DLL Hell is alive and well on Linux, too.

Answer (score 10):

## LD_PRELOAD is more powerful

The most important difference is that LD_PRELOAD can replace functions *statically* linked into a binary.

### Example

If ever you find that LD_PRELOAD works for you, but LD_LIBRARY_PATH mysteriously does not, this, almost certainly, is the reason why.

For example, I was debugging [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) in `bash` and was confused at first why my modified libreadline.so was loading with LD_PRELOAD but not LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=shlib/libreadline.so bash -
(worked)

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=shlib/ bash -
(failed)
```

Taking a look with the [ldd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) command, which lists dependencies on dynamically linked libraries, gives the answer:

```sh
$ ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Sure enough, libreadline is not listed as one of the shared libraries. Therefore, /bin/bash on my machine must have been statically linked with its own version of libreadline at compile time. The reason LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work is because the binary never asks the dynamic linker (ld.so) to load libreadline.

LD_PRELOAD, on the other hand, loads the library no matter what, allowing a library to override even statically linked functions.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. LD_PRELOAD shouldn't be able to replace references to statically linked objects; it only understands dynamic relocations.

Comment: Perhaps it _shouldn't_, but it definitely does. Do you have a suggestion for how I could improve this answer to make it more clear that it is based on actual behavior and not just my opinion? Would it help if I included verbatim output with LD_DEBUG=all? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, LD_DEBUG output might help. I think that bash is dlopen'ing libreadline here, rather than statically linking to it.

Comment: Good question. I did not discuss dlopen in the answer because the version of bash I was compiling (v5, IIRC) was statically linked with libreadline.a included with the bash source code.

Comment: How do you know that it was statically linked and not dlopen'd?

Comment: You can see it [in the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/Makefile.in#n252). I just double-checked with `nm` after recompiling bash 5.1 and sure enough readline() is marked as "T" (defined in text=code section). I couldn't find any evidence dlopen is used for readline. Is there something you see that I'm missing?

Comment: @64_ By the way, `LD_DEBUG=libs LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=foo bash; grep readline foo.*` returns no hits. Is that the answer you're looking for? I double-checked by compiling the example from [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html#EXAMPLES) and grepping for libm and LD_DEBUG does work correctly with dlopen'd libraries.

Comment: One can construct an example to show that LD_PRELOAD does not affect calls to statically linked code. The libc just isn't able to patch text addresses at runtime to change these things. But I'm also confused about the behaviour in your example. I would be really curious to see a GDB backtrace into your modified and preloaded libreadline.so, or some other reproduction with similar behaviour.

Comment: It is not libc, but ld.so that handles runtime linking, but I see your point. A completely statically linked binary (gcc -static) would never call ld.so, so LD_PRELOAD would have no effect. I should correct my answer to make clear I am speaking of mixed dynamic and static binaries. Please try compiling bash. You'll see it links to a static library (with `-L lib/readline -lreadline` which pulls in the file lib/readline/libreadline.a).  The executable is dynamically linked, just not with libreadline. And, yet, LD_PRELOAD is able to override the libreadline function.

Comment: As for _why_ this works, I hypothesize that `patchelf --add-needed libreadline.so.6 bash` would cause LD_LIBRARY_PATH to work the same as LD_PRELOAD and override the static library functions that had been compiled in.